# Dual boot ubuntu 14.04 with ubunut 14.04

Tags: 14.04, grub2

I had ubuntu 14.04 with windows 8.1 and I deleted windows 8.1 partition with system reserved partition and when I reboot the system it did not boot.

Then I used a live usb and try to save followed many tutorials and I even rewrite sector 32 according to

"ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1661254"

finally I used boot-rescue and got over installing another ubuntu installation alongside ubuntu 14.04.

I was hoping to keep it but when I load into my old ubuntu installation nothing seems to work fine, like it does not boot correctly I can't get into my user account but the guest account. When I log it comes back to login screen. And I get many errors upon booting that OS image, like cannot connect to ubuntu live failed ( tell me if need more information)

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8198904/

please check above link and tell me what is wrong

my old ubuntu is on sda9 and new one is on sda1

Gparted Image and Terminal `fdisk -lu` and `df -h` images

[image]

[image]